# Twitter api - search too complex?

Tags: search, twitter

Any idea why Twitter is throwing this error?

```
GET https://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=Middle%20Tennessee%20State%20Blue%20Raiders%20Florida%20International%20Golden%20Panthers%20win%20OR%20lose%20-rt%20-from%3Aespn&&lang=en&since=2011-02-09: 403: Sorry, your query is too complex. Please reduce complexity and try again.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554756/Twitter-Search-API-Method%3a-search).  "Queries are limited 140 URL encoded characters."  You query string is 156 characters.

Comment: That documentation URL is now broken. Do you have a newer URL that mentions the search maximum complexity guidelines?

Comment: @Darren Cook: I am not sure there is one anymore.

Answer (score 6):

As of August 2011, at least, it appears max query string length is quite high. It worked fine for me with a maxlength of 300; when I moved to 500 characters I ended up with three queries, the 2nd of which failed:

- q1: OK: 491 characters, 23 OR clauses
- q2: FAILED: 493 characters, 39 OR clauses
- q3: OK: 203 characters, 17 OR clauses

So, it might turn out to be 492+ characters, or it might be 24+ clauses. I suspect some combination.

I've not spent more time narrowing it down further, as if the guidelines were fixed then Twitter would publish them. I'm going to split my queries at 300 characters or 20 clauses, whichever comes first, and hope that is reasonably future-proof.

**UPDATE:** Under "Best Practices" on https://dev.twitter.com/docs/using-search they suggest limiting a query to 10 clauses. Obviously from my above results it is not the current hard limit, but 10 should be the future-proof limit I was after.

P.S. Back to the actual question, I notice you have a "&&" typo in your query. It wonder if this could have triggered the complaint? (untested idea)

Answer (score 3):

On 8th February 2018:

1. Twitter search limites to **50** `OR` **clauses** (Notice 50 OR clauses contains 49 `OR` because for example `word1 OR word2` contains two clauses and one `OR`).
2. Twitter search limites to **500** characters.

My test for the OR clause is:

- This search works: `h1 OR h2 OR h3 OR h4 OR h5 OR h6 OR h7 OR h8 OR h9 OR h10 OR h11 OR h12 OR h13 OR h14 OR h15 OR h16 OR h17 OR h18 OR h19 OR h20 OR h21 OR h22 OR h23 OR h24 OR h25 OR h26 OR h27 OR h28 OR h29 OR h30 OR h31 OR h32 OR h33 OR h34 OR h35 OR h36 OR h37 OR h38 OR h39 OR h40 OR h41 OR h42 OR h43 OR h44 OR h45 OR h46 OR h47 OR h48 OR h49 OR h50`
- However, if we add: `OR h51`, it fails

My test for the characters count is:

- This search works (500 characters): `hell1 OR hell2 OR hell3 OR hell4 OR hell5 OR hell6 OR hell7 OR hell8 OR hell9 OR hell10 OR hell11 OR hell12 OR hell13 OR hell14 OR hell15 OR hell16 OR hell17 OR hell18 OR hell19 OR hell20 OR hell21 OR hell22 OR hell23 OR hell24 OR hell25 OR hell26 OR hell27 OR hell28 OR hell29 OR hell30 OR hell31 OR hell32 OR hell33 OR hell34 OR hell35 OR hell36 OR hell37 OR hell38 OR hell39 OR hell40 OR hell41 OR hell42 OR hell43 OR hell44 OR hell45 OR hell46 OR hell47 OR hell48 OR hell49 OR hell50abcdefghijklm`
- However, if we add the n (501 characters) to the last word (`hell50abcdefghijklmn`), it fails.

Notice I have just realised that if we remove the character `o` to the word `hello`, the result is `hell` (is the World sending me a message? xD)